# Cygwin/vim Windows 7 file access issue

Tags: vim, windows-7, cygwin

It appears that on Windows 7 Cygwin/vim thinks all files are read only.  You can edit the files fine in Textpad/Notepad but vim thinks they are read only.  There are  number of [reported](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cygwin+vi+read+only#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=cygwin+vi+read+only+windows+7+&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=dc7471560451cb46) occurrences but I can't see a solution.  ??

---

**Update**: Per accepted answer, created the file `C:\cygwin\etc\fstab.d\myname` with the entry below.

```
none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0,acl
```

Per the comment you'll see in `C:\cygwin\etc\fstab`, this statement is the default Cygwin mount, save for the `acl` which I added.

Comment: @MatthewWilson +1 for correct order. In addition, I have to use `none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user,noacl 0 0` on Windows 8.

Comment: Even if i use Windows 7, i've had to add the `noacl` Option to get write access to my files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin tries to impose a POSIX compatibility layer over the windows access control lists, which often leads to many problems.

In older versions of Cygwin a cheap solution was to disable this POSIX compatibility layer by setting the environment variable "CYGWIN=ntsec". Nowadays it seems as one must set the "acl" option for your drive(s).

http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

This has some drawbacks. If you try to run a secured cygwin installation for multiple users, then better use a real linux, this will save so much hassle.

Answer (score 3):

I guess another solution would be to use the native version of Vim instead of the cygwin one.